# DataTables - oLanguage.sInfo issue

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables

I have a problem with Datatables oLanguage.sInfo. When there are more than 999 entries, the variable *TOTAL* is wrong.

The main problem is that there is a string `undefined` inserted.

Eg, it shows not  `1 to 50 of 5,601 entries` but `1 bis 50 von 5undefined601`

```
$.extend(
   $.fn.dataTable.defaults, 
     { "oLanguage": { "sInfo": "START bis END von TOTAL Einträgen", ... 
   } 
});
```

DataTables 1.10.7
More details: http://debug.datatables.net/iqifax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to fix this:

```
"oLanguage": {
    "sThousands": ".",
```